# Using partial fractions and Laplace transform to solve a second order initial-value problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would I solve this problem, using Laplace transform and partial fractions?

$y''+3y'$=$-3t$, where    $y(0)=-1$ and  $y'(0)=1$.

Comment: The tag [tag:differential-equations] is intended for questions about ordinary differential equations; see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/differential-equations/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.) There is no need to create a new tag called [tag:ordinary].

Answer (score 1):

You should first know that, if

$$\hat{y}(s) = \int_0^{\infty} dt \: y(t) e^{-s t}$$

is the LT of $y$, then the LT of the first and second derivative of $y$ is

$$\hat{y'}(s) = -y(0) + s \hat{y}(s) = 1 + s \hat{y}(s)$$
$$\hat{y''}(s) = -y'(0) - s y(0) + s^2 \hat{y}(s) = -1 + s + s^2 \hat{y}(s)$$

which may be shown by integration by parts.  The differential equation becomes

$$[ -1 + s + s^2 \hat{y}(s)] + 3 [1 + s \hat{y}(s)] = -3 \int_0^{\infty} dt \: t \, e^{-s t} = -\frac{3}{s^2} $$

which implies

$$(s^2+3 s) \hat{y}(s) = - \left ( 2+s+\frac{3}{s^2}\right)$$

or

$$\hat{y}(s) = - \frac{s^3+2 s^2 + 3}{s^3 (s+3)}$$

Because of the form of the denominator, we see a partial fractions decomposition of the form $A/s + B/s^2 + C/s^3 + D/(s+3)$.  Doing the algebra, we find that

$$- \frac{s^3+2 s^2 + 3}{s^3 (s+3)} = -\frac{7}{9 s} + \frac{1}{3 s^2} - \frac{1}{s^3} - \frac{2}{9 (s+3)}$$

To find $y(t)$,use the inverse LT.  In this, it is straightforward because we have used decomposition.  Note that ILT $1/s$ is $1$, $1/(s+3)$ is $e^{-3 t}$, etc.  The answer is

$$y(t) = -\frac{7}{9} - \frac{2}{9} e^{-3 t} + \frac{1}{3} t  - \frac{1}{2} t^2$$

Comment: Nicely done. So my $A,B,C,D$ can be found from the explicit work here.

Comment: Yes.  The LT takes the initial conditions into account, and I find it useful to integrate it into the analysis as I go.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the transform into the $s$-domain,
$$ s^2Y+s-1+3sY =-3/s^2 $$
hence solving algebraically for $Y$,
$$ Y = \frac{1}{s^2+3s} \left(1-s-\frac{3}{s^2} \right) $$
Now do partial fractions on this expression: find $A,B,C,D$ such that
$$ Y(s) = \frac{A}{s+3}+\frac{B}{s}+\frac{2C}{s^2}+\frac{6D}{s^3} $$
Once you find these constants $A,B,C,D$ the answer is found by inverse Laplace transforms:
$$y(t) =  Ae^{-3t}+B+Ct+Dt^2 $$
That's the method. Of course, this problem is also neatly solved by annihilator-motivated undetermined coefficients as the other answer shows. I believe this is what you wanted, modulo the details I'm too lazy to provide at the moment.